# Unable to parse AWS DynamoDB binary get item in boto3 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have got the items from AWS dynamodb as dict which has a value in binary format.
I am not able to retrieve the value of a binary content.

Below is the sample.

```
my_details  = {'route': Binary(b'gAAAABgLNW9tNcpeclIy1LSs8wKYRy9uMxgr5V4TwJmEJNZ2WVlb3Z3LtIK3PewO2SDRYkvXAh8bcZ4Ej_jBjaNi8xhU1-P2FLpcGEX2g='), 'way': '5064', '
stop': Binary(b'\xf1J\xef\xa0\xac\xb1A0\xa9\\:'), 'name': 'cfcf57'}

print(type(my_details['route']))

print(my_details['route'])
print(my_details['way'])
```

I need value of the `route` key like below

```
gAAAABgLNW9tNcpeclIy1LSs8wKYRy9uMxgr5V4TwJmEJNZ2WVlb3Z3LtIK3PewO2SDRYkvXAh8bcZ4Ej_jBjaNi8xhU1-P2FLpcGEX2g=
```

I have tried to get the value of `route` using `mydetails['route']` but got below error

```
<class 'boto3.dynamodb.types.Binary'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Prabhakar/Documents/Projects/Test.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(my_details['route'])
    
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
```

Please let me know how can I retrieve the binary content in python dict.

Answer (score 2):

when you call `print(my_details['route'])`, the actual call is `print(str(my_details['route']))`.

`boto3.dynamodb.types.Binary` define is

```
class Binary:
    """A class for representing Binary in dynamodb

    Especially for Python 2, use this class to explicitly specify
    binary data for item in DynamoDB. It is essentially a wrapper around
    binary. Unicode and Python 3 string types are not allowed.
    """

    def __init__(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, BINARY_TYPES):
            types = ', '.join([str(t) for t in BINARY_TYPES])
            raise TypeError(f'Value must be of the following types: {types}')
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Binary):
            return self.value == other.value
        return self.value == other

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Binary({self.value!r})'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    def __bytes__(self):
        return self.value

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)
```

then the actual call is `print(my_details['route'].__str__())`, the return type is `bytes`, so you get the type error:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
```

so what you need is just `print(bytes(my_details['route']))`, or `print(str(bytes(my_details['route'])))`

Python's types are really confusing！

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

It is returning data with `byte` type, to get it in `str` type, you have to call `.decode` method on it. Here is the documentation for that: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode